# Remove time info from google map

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

I have google map with routes on my website and I want to remove white time info box.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m46!1m12!1m3!1d204152.56634698433!2d174.4756264675282!3d-36.9170414111374!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m31!3e0!4m5!1s0x6d0d47f01acf61c9%3A0x1300ef6107147fb1!2s82+Federal+Street%2C+Auckland!3m2!1d-36.848918!2d174.762316!4m5!1s0x6d0d6f84ac9df8e1%3A0x2a00ef6165df7dd0!2sKarekare+Stream%2C+Karekare%2C+Auckland!3m2!1d-36.986930799999996!2d174.4746851!4m5!1s0x6d0d6f035335b4e1%3A0x500ef6143a2f790!2sPiha!3m2!1d-36.9530211!2d174.46880919999998!4m5!1s0x6d0d6aeadce234bf%3A0x500ef6143a306f0!2sSwanson%2C+Auckland!3m2!1d-36.8656784!2d174.57980329999998!4m5!1s0x6d0d47f01acf61c9%3A0x1300ef6107147fb1!2s82+Federal+St%2C+Auckland%2C+Auckland!3m2!1d-36.848918!2d174.762316!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snz!4v1468509676781" width="1200" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Also I want to remove this white box

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizations like that are not possible with the default embedding of Google Maps. You have much more options if you use the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/?hl=en). Therefor you have to [get an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=en) and can use it e.g. to [disable the UI](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI).

Just search the Google Maps API for suitable options for your application.